# Combining two user databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two apps.  They are different code bases.  One is in Rails 3.2 and the other is in Rails 4, one on Heroku, one on AWS, both use postgresql.  I have users that are signing in to both apps.  I would like to make it so that if you signed up for one app (a specific one) then you can use that log in information to sign into the second app.

What is the best way to go about doing this, give one omniauth functionality?
What is the simplest/fastest way to do this, seed one database with other database info?

I know best and fastest might be different approaches.

Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head, expose an authentication API on both applications and use one's method in another's authentication process. So if a user signs up in application A his data is in application a. When he signs in first try to authenticate on application a, then use API from application B and if both fail then you can redirect him to sign up or whatever.

This was you don't have to duplicate data from one db to the other.